# How to apply multiple orderby in linq query

Tags: linq, sorting

I want to apply order by on multiple columns some ascending and others are in descending order in LINQ. How can i do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var sortedCollection =
    from item in collection
    orderby item.Property1, item.Property2 descending, item.Property3
    select item;
```

Answer (score 28):

Borrowing from [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#thenByDescendingSimple):

```
orderby p.Category, p.UnitPrice descending
```

or as a Lambda:

```
products.OrderBy(p => p.Category).ThenByDescending(p => p.UnitPrice);
```

Answer (score 9):

Steven's answer will work, but I prefer method chaining to declarative LINQ syntax, e.g.

```
collection
    .OrderBy(e => e.Property1)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Property2)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Property3)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? LINQ is much more readable than extension methods and lambda's.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. When reading/writing code I don't like having to make the context switch between method based C# code and declarative LINQ code. I find it easier to read and see what's going on when method chaining is used. Also, ultimately, the LINQ is converted to method calls by the compiler so I prefer to go straight to the horse's mouth and have my code more directly reflect the statements which are executed (JIT compiled) at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

should be simply a matter of stating

```
orderby x, y descending, z
```

see [good old ms examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#thenByDescendingSimple)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and as an alternative to the other good answers here...

There is also an overload or OrderBy that takes an IComparer, if this is a common order pattern that you want, then you might like to create a class that imlements that and pass it to the orderby clause, let it handle the more complex ordering, that way its re-usable for when ever you are ordering your query the same way.