# Ordering linq query with secondary sort

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple “order by” in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

I have a list of orders and I need to order it by the date of the order and then a secondary sort by the price of the order. I'm not sure how exactly to do this since I tried orders.OrderBy(o => o.Date).OrderBy(o => o.Price), but it doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: its weird how many of this exact same question I've seen today.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I just googled `Ordering linq query with secondary sort` and found the answer on the first page to a [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq) post.

Comment: actually, its a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318885/multiple-order-by-with-linq), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613602/how-to-apply-multiple-orderby-in-linq-query), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958220/how-can-i-use-linq-to-sort-by-multiple-fields),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270374/linq-multiple-order-by),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084671/linq-multiple-order-by), etc

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site... tried to find it but I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want to use the ThenBy function:

`orders.OrderBy(o => o.Date).ThenBy(o => o.Price)`

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to use the LINQ query syntax instead of the method syntax:

```
 List<Order> sortedOrders = from o in orders
 orderby o.Date, O.Price
 select o;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly - the use of two fields within 'orderby' separated by a comma results in a form of grouping if the o.Date has a bunch of records of the same Date value - ordering the records O.Price ascending within the matching Date. ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Same as the accepted answer.  Just using a different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> orders.OrderBy(o => o.Date).ThenBy(o => o.Price)